# How can I track the details of all the objects created when I acess an application in Java

Tags: java

How can I track the details of all the objects created when I access  an application in Java.

context : I have a simple application and I want my user to be able to run multiple instances. I want the application to know how many instances of the application and per application instance, how many objects(internal to my app) are being created and currently running.

Comment: what is the reason making you track objects created ? and are you using Aspect Oriented Programming (Spring AOP, AspectJ etc) ?

Comment: This is to broad, what do you want to track exactly, the number of instance create, the instances itself. What about the instance that are no longer used by the application (if you keep a reference somewhere, it will remain in memory). Please try to ask a more specific and more detail question.

Comment: Hi Axelh, I edited my question above. I want to track down the number of instances of my app + number of instances being created in each instance of my app. and no i dont want any info about the objects that are no longer used. I hope this explains my problem. FYI , am in the design mode of my application .

Comment: Can you please add how this app is deployed what frameworks used and what type standalone or web ? What server ? etc..

Comment: this is a web application .(As am in analysis of this not sure it would be distributed one or not). Spring framework and server would be Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Adding variable to count the number of objects created would be the simplest way as below:

```
public class Class1 {

private volatile static int counter=0;

public Class1() {
    counter++;
   }

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    counter--;
    super.finalize();
   }
}
```

If you are using AOP then this cumbersome code can be written and applied from a single place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried it already and this way I would need to put a counter in each class of my app that would be cumbersome.

Comment: yes and that is why you need to use AOP. This article describes how https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/how-to-count-java-objects-in-memory/